# Theme does not apply to Reset Password page at Admin: Magento 1.9.3.6

Tags: password, magento-1.9.3.6

I applied new theme to Magento Admin. All the pages and new modules have this new theme / css. But the Reset Password page does not has this new theme / css. 
Can anybody help me why theme does not apply to Reset Password page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer. I have found that, for individual pages we have to apply the the theme seperately and I did it for Reset Password page as well.

Thanks

Comment: Hope below file-path will be useful to somone. Path of the file: <project_directory>/app/design/adminhtml/default/<theme_direcory>/template/forgotpassword.phtml. I copied this file from its original location i.e. <project_directory>/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/forgotpassword.phtml and applied class of the theme and design changed. Thanks